# How does Apache "advise" children to stop with graceful-stop

Tags: apache-2.4

In the apache webserver docs, I see that you can use [`apachectl -k graceful-stop` or a WINCH signal](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/stopping.html#gracefulstop) to stop Apache, and when you do so:

> The WINCH or graceful-stop signal causes the parent process to advise the children to exit after their current request (or to exit immediately if they're not serving anything)

However, I can't seem to find anything that documents what exactly is meant by "advising" the children to exit. Does it send them a signal? Something else?

Comment: This probably depends on which mpm you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

The master process takes the signal, but the IPC with the children is via pipe.

> While the administrator controls the master server by signals only,
> the master server uses either signals or a pipe to control the number
> of child servers, the Pipe of Death. (Apache 1.3 used signals only).
>
> A graceful restart should affect primarily the idle child server
> processes. While Apache 1.3 just sent a SIGUSR1 signal to the
> process group, Apache 2 puts "Char of Death'' items into the Pipe of
> Death (pod). The busy child servers will check the pipe after
> processing a request, even before comparing their generation. In both
> cases they set the die_now flag and terminate upon beginning a new
> iteration in the request-response loop
>
> Apache Modeling Project [4.3.3.5.2 Master Server controls the child servers](http://www.fmc-modeling.org/category/projects/apache/amp/4_3Multitasking_server.html)

Note that this allows control of child processes without them having to respond immediately to signals.

This analysis is from an earlier httpd version. Look at the source code for the precise current behavior, but at a high level this should still apply.